# Bootstrap Side navigation not showing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap side nav for my one page template like below:

```html
 <head> 
 <script> jQuery(document).ready(function(e){ $('#mySidenav ul li a').on('click', function(e){
            $(".sidenav").hide();  });  }); </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript"> <!--
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           if(e.style.display == 'block')
              e.style.display = 'none';
           else
              e.style.display = 'block';
        } //--> </script> 
        </head>
    
    
    Nav div code
    
 <nav> 
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">   
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onClick="closeNav()">&times;</a>   
    <ul>   
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#testimonial">Testimonial</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>   
    </ul>   
    <div class="ad"><img src="assets/images/ad.jpg" alt="ad">
    </div> 
    </div> 
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onClick="openNav()" class="open">&#9776;</span> 
    <script> function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px"; }
    
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0"; } 
        </script> 
 </nav>
```

Once visiting a section of the page next time menu do not show?? What should I do?? Any solution.  I want to show sections only on clicking link not whole nav div.
Thanks!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Comment: Hi is it possible to hide a div on clicking an anchor link in same div and after visiting the link again div can be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try something as like below.

```js
$('#mySidenav a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var hash = this.hash;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800);
  closeNav();
});


function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openNav {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
    </a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#services">Services</a>
    <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
  <span class="openNav" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;
    open</span>
  <div id="about" class="section">About</div>
  <div id="services" class="section">Services</div>
  <div id="clients" class="section">Clients</div>
  <div id="contact" class="section">Contact</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh thanks but not working yet. Is it possible to amend some jquery in my code so as I could get what I exactly want?

Comment: Hi I have made it but I want sidenav hide when we click about link and go to about section of page then again clicking open sidenav displays means when we access about section sidenav hides so as content is only visible.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to hide your side nav when clicking on any of the link in it. Am I right? that is what i made here.

Comment: still bit confused about your requirement. check the updated answer once.

Comment: Bootstrap side nav  should hide automatically as link is clicked and we only see content on page like in thegramin.biz when viewed in mobile we go to about section and expanded menu automatically closes after link is clicked.